# How to collect multiple state flow in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

How to collect two state flow in activity? Because mine only the first flow that consumed.

For example, inside viewmodel is like this:

```
class ExampleViewModel: ViewModel(){
    private val state = MutableStateFlow<HomeMainFragmentState>(HomeMainFragmentState.Init)
    private val products = MutableStateFlow<List<ProductEntity>>(mutableListOf())


    //to be consumed
    fun getState() : StateFlow<HomeMainFragmentState> = state
    fun getProducts() : StateFlow<List<ProductEntity>> = products
}
```

And then in my view is like this:

```
private fun observe(){
      viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
      viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED){
            viewModel.getState().collect { state -> handleState(state) }
            viewModel.getProducts().collect{ products -> handleProducts(products) }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, **only the first flow is consumed, for this case is the 'state'**, the **products** was never consumed/executed by activity/fragment.

How to fix this?
I also read about combining the flow, does it mean the second flow depends on first flow to run?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Calling `collect` on a Flow suspends the coroutine until the Flow is complete. For a MutableStateFlow, it will only be complete when it's cancelled. So usually, when you call `collect` on a Flow, you don't do anything else in the coroutine underneath that call.

If you want to collect each of these flows individually, you need two coroutines.

The `flowOnLifecycle` function will give you a bit cleaner code, so it's not as painful to have two coroutines:

```
private fun observe(){
    viewModel.getState()
        .flowOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
        .onEach { state -> handleState(state) }
        .launchIn(lifecycleScope)
    viewModel.getProducts()
        .flowOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
        .onEach { products -> handleProducts(products) }
        .launchIn(lifecycleScope)
}
```

I also want to mention, function names like `getState` are unnatural in Kotlin, except when they are heavy functions (and even if it were a heavy function that has to calculate something, I would prefer `generateState` or `calculateState`). It's more proper to use a property:

```
private val mutableState = MutableStateFlow<HomeMainFragmentState>(HomeMainFragmentState.Init)
val state: StateFlow<HomeMainFragmentState> get() = mutableState
```

They have said that in a **future** version of Kotlin, there will probably be a better syntax for exposing a read-only version of a mutable class that doesn't require a second property. Something like this:

```
private val state = MutableStateFlow<HomeMainFragmentState>(HomeMainFragmentState.Init)
    public get(): StateFlow<HomeMainFragmentState>
```

Comment: Ah I See, I need to two coroutine then. 
Changing my viewmodel as your suggestion:

`private val state = MutableStateFlow<HomeMainFragmentState(HomeMainFragmentState.Init)
val pState: StateFlow<HomeMainFragmentState> get() = state`


and then consume it like:
` viewModel.pState.flowWithLifecycle(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED).onEach { state ->
            handleState(state)
        }.launchIn(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope)`


solved my problems. also it is more readable. thanks

Answer (score 20):

You must use the `CoroutineScope.launch` function for each collector.

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED){
        launch {
            viewModel.getState().collect { state -> handleState(state) }
        }
        launch {
            viewModel.getProducts().collect{ products -> handleProducts(products) }
        }
    }
}
```